# Angular 4- Error - Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, ngfor

There is a nested response coming from HTTP:

```
 this.dataSet = Observable.of({
     "insideData": [{
         id: "1"
         requiredData:[{
             firstname:"Amy"
             lastname: "Amy"
         }, {
             firstname:"John"
             lastname: "John"
        }]
    }]
 }}).map(mydata => mydata.insideData);
```

I include this in another Observable in component and try to reduce this into nesting of requiredData array.

```
getItem(id) {    //id here is needed to get the first loop matching the id
    this.filteredData = this.dataSet.find(data => data.id ===id);
    this.gettingRequiredData = this.filteredData.map(data => data[0].json())
       .map(data => data.requiredData.json() || []);
}
```

In HTML I have a ngFor loop which is iterating the requiredDataSet

```
<div *ngFor="let data of gettingRequiredData; index as i;">......</div>
```

While running this code it is giving

```
  ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I am not sure why it is picking as object and not array

Comment: As it stands, `this.dataSet` is an Observable

Comment: So what changes shall i make so that it iterates

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the async pipe when binding to the observable.  This is what is necessary to subscribe to the Observable and emit values.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of gettingRequiredData | async; index as i;">......</div>
```

Comment: When i try doing this it gives Cannot read property '0' of undefined for this.gettingRequiredData = this.filteredData.map(data => data[0].json()) this line

Comment: Yes, because your expression in find will never return anything if your sample data is to believed.  My solution fixed the problem you asked about, but you have a whole bunch of other issues in your code that are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Oh you mean to say Rxjs mapping is not done in the right way and i should iterate it differently